# PHP Parsing error: "Parse Error received on unexpected T_ENCAPSED AND WHITESPACE."

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, whitespace

I am receiving a PHP Error:

```
Parse Error received on unexpected T_ENCAPSED AND WHITESPACE.
```

The line: `($insert .= "($POST...)` is the one that is generates the error.

```
(string)$insert;
if(is_array($_POST['Year']))
{
    foreach($_POST['Year'] as $k=>$v)
    {
        //the following line returns the error
        $insert .= "($_POST['Name'][$k], $_POST['One'][$k], $_POST['Two'][$k], $_POST['Four'][$k], $_POST['Eight'][$k], $_POST['Fifteen'][$k], $_POST['LJump'][$k], $_POST['HJump'][$k], $_POST['Shotputt'][$k], $_POST['Discuss'][$k], $_POST['Javelin'][$k], $_POST['Date'][$k], $_POST['Year'][$k]),";
    }
    $insert = substr_replace($insert ,0,-1);
}
else
{
    $insert .= "($_POST['Name'], $_POST['One'], $_POST['Two'], $_POST['Four'], $_POST['Eight'], $_POST['Fifteen'], $_POST['LJump'], $_POST['HJump'], $_POST['Shotputt'], $_POST['Discuss'], $_POST['Javelin'], $_POST['Date'], $_POST['Year'])";
}

$sql="INSERT INTO results_main 
(Name, One, Two, Four, Eight, Fifteen, LJump, HJump, Shotputt, Discuss, Javelin, Date, Year)
VALUES 
".$insert;

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote my question can you at least provide some sort of feedback?

Comment: You have a `dot` in the first `$insert .=`, and none in the second. Remove the first dot, and put it in the second `$insert =`.

Comment: Sorry, where do i need to put the `dot`s?

Comment: I would test and see to remove the first dot. Try `$insert = "($_POST['Name'][$k],` and `$insert = "($_POST['Name'],`. Somehow that doesn't seem right, you're concatenating.

Comment: Feedback: you mis-spelled several words.  Post includes a mini rant on how frustrated you are (irrelevant to other people who land on this page), you didn't highlight the error in its own block to make it pop out.  Code does not "kick up a fuss".  What does kick up fuss mean?  You aren't thinking clearly about what the error is nor what you want.  It's hard to read your mind.  And your code is not properly formatted (tabs and spaces in random ways).   Finally, the question is "too localized". And thus, down votes are an attempt by us to get you to stop doing those annoying things.

Comment: Feedback part 2:  Your code block does not fit in the 80 character width.  Hard for people to "see" the code without fiddling with a scrollbar.  Someone will eventually clean up after you, and this will no longer apply.  But if we don't hold you to a higher standard, you may never hold yourself to it.

Comment: Sorry Eric, didnt know the internet police were around these parts, ill refrain from using this site then. Thanks to everyone who actually tried to help me. Dyslexia means that my spelling isnt top notch, and formatting is changing from me copy and pasting

Comment: If you want a website with nobody like me, you are welcome to post on yahoo answers.  There you can post anything, and you'll get responses.  But there will be no experts there, because A players don't suffer fools well.

Comment: props for that answer that was a good comeback, you must understand my frustration though. I have tried all suggestions given to me and cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic PHP syntax: you cannot use quoted array keys within a double-quoted string:

```
$x = "$array['key']";
             ^---^--- wrong
```

it should either be:

```
$x = "{$array['key']}";
      ^--           ^--- note the braces
or
$x = "$array[key]";
             ^--^-- note lack of ' quotes
```

You are also wide open and begging for an [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com). So learn about that BEFORE you do any OTHER coding.

Comment: I have implemented this and still recieving the same error. Just to confirm, I have removed quotes around the Year array key.

Comment: you have to remote ALL of the quoted keys in EVERY $_POST variable, or at least use the `{}` notation to encapsulate them.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on SQL injection, however my knowledge is very old and this application will be on a LAN with no outside access, so its not a priority at the moment, deployment is. I will try what you hae suggested now

Comment: Only one question per stackoverflow post please.  If you fix the error defined at the top, and receive a new error, make a new question.  But be careful if it's too similar you'll get down votes.